# Easyrec: Undocumented API to delete items?

Tags: api, recommendation-engine

I am looking a way to delete and disable an item through API, but could not find any. Then I looked at the admin page code and found out API to delete and activate/deactivate in item.js https://sourceforge.net/p/easyrec/code/ci/master/tree/easyrec-web/src/main/webapp/js/item.js

Is this some internal API or can I use it in my application?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer I got for Easyrec forum:

> The mentioned call would only work if you are logged in and have the
>   session cookies. To deactivate an item you can use the [setitemactive
>   API call](http://easyrec.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/REST_API_v0.98#set_item_active)
>
> It is not possible to delete items.